# Using java netcdfAll to read NOAA CFS (grib) file

Tags: java, netcdf, grib, noaa

I have downloaded this file from the [noaa site](https://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/cfsr/197901/prate.gdas.197901.grb2)

Using netcdfAll I can see the variable metadata

```
[int GaussLatLon_Projection;
  :grid_mapping_name = "latitude_longitude";
  :earth_radius = 6371229.0; // double
, float lat(lat=576);
  :units = "degrees_north";
, float lon(lon=1152);
  :units = "degrees_east";
, double reftime(reftime=124);
  :units = "Hour since 1979-01-01T00:00:00Z";
  :standard_name = "forecast_reference_time";
  :long_name = "GRIB reference time";
  :calendar = "proleptic_gregorian";
, double time(reftime=124, time=6);
  :units = "Hour since 1979-01-01T00:00:00Z";
  :standard_name = "time";
  :long_name = "GRIB forecast or observation time";
  :calendar = "proleptic_gregorian";
  :bounds = "time_bounds";
, double time_bounds(reftime=124, time=6, 2);
  :units = "Hour since 1979-01-01T00:00:00Z";
  :long_name = "bounds for time";
, float Precipitation_rate_surface_Mixed_intervals_Average(reftime=124, time=6, lat=576, lon=1152);
  :long_name = "Precipitation rate (Mixed_intervals Average) @ Ground or water surface";
  :units = "kg.m-2.s-1";
  :abbreviation = "PRATE";
  :missing_value = NaNf; // float
  :grid_mapping = "GaussLatLon_Projection";
  :coordinates = "reftime time lat lon ";
  :Grib_Statistical_Interval_Type = "Average";
  :Grib_Variable_Id = "VAR_0-1-7_L1_Imixed_S0";
  :Grib2_Parameter = 0, 1, 7; // int
  :Grib2_Parameter_Discipline = "Meteorological products";
  :Grib2_Parameter_Category = "Moisture";
  :Grib2_Parameter_Name = "Precipitation rate";
  :Grib2_Level_Type = 1; // int
  :Grib2_Level_Desc = "Ground or water surface";
  :Grib2_Generating_Process_Type = "Forecast";
]
```

I understand that the measurement time is a combination of a 6 hourly reference time `reftime`, with hourly offsets defined by `time`.
If I open the grib file in Panoply (or in python using pygrib) I can see that the measurement times are as follows

```
1979-01-01T00:00:00Z - 1979-01-01T00:00:00Z
1979-01-01T00:00:00Z - 1979-01-01T00:01:00Z
1979-01-01T00:00:00Z - 1979-01-01T00:02:00Z
1979-01-01T00:00:00Z - 1979-01-01T00:03:00Z
1979-01-01T00:00:00Z - 1979-01-01T00:04:00Z
1979-01-01T00:00:00Z - 1979-01-01T00:05:00Z
1979-01-01T00:00:00Z - 1979-01-01T00:06:00Z
1979-01-01T00:06:00Z - 1979-01-01T00:06:00Z
...
```

It appears that Panoply & pygrib are showing the reference times as well as the forecast times.
However if I read the file in Java using netcdfAll (see code at the bottom) I don't see duplicate timestamps. I presumably only see the forecast times, as netcdfAll is filtering out the reference measurements. Is that correct?

According to the Noaa timeseries reference the f00 reference time should be ignored. So does it matter that netcdfAll is filtering out the reference time measurements?
https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/sites/default/files/attachments/CFSR-Hourly-Timeseries.pdf

```
NetcdfFile ncfile = NetcdfFile.open(filename);

System.out.println(ncfile.getVariables().toString());

String varName = "Precipitation_rate_surface_Mixed_intervals_Average";
String latName = "lat";
String lonName = "lon";
String timeName = "time";
String reftimeName = "reftime";
String time_boundsName = "time_bounds";

Variable prate = ncfile.findVariable(varName);
if (null == prate) {
    System.out.println("variable does not exist: "+varName);
    return null;
}

Variable lat = ncfile.findVariable(latName);
Variable lon = ncfile.findVariable(lonName);
Variable time = ncfile.findVariable(timeName);
Variable reftime = ncfile.findVariable(reftimeName);
Variable time_bounds = ncfile.findVariable(time_boundsName);

ZonedDateTime basetime = ZonedDateTime.parse("1979-01-01T00:00:00Z");

try {
        // reftime + time = hours since 1979-01-01T00:00:00Z
        int index_lat = 0;
        int index_lon = 0;

        int[] shape = vars.prate.getShape();

        Array data_timeAll = vars.time.read(); // "reftime, hrs since ref (0-6)"
        Array data_timeboundsAll = vars.time.read(); // "reftime, hrs since ref (0-6)"

        // loop reftime
        for(int index_reftime = 0; index_reftime < shape[0]; index_reftime++) {

        // loop time 
            for(int index_time = 0; index_time < shape[1]; index_time++) {
                // reftime(124), time(6), lat(576), lon(1152)
                Array data = vars.prate.read(
                index_reftime + "," +
                index_time + ", 0, 0");

                Array data_lat = vars.lat.read("0");
                Array data_lon = vars.lon.read("0");
                Array data_time = vars.time.read(
                index_reftime + "," + index_time); // "reftime, hrs since ref (0-6)"
                Array data_reftime = vars.reftime.read(Integer.toString(index_reftime));

                System.out.println("----------------");
                System.out.println(index_reftime + "," + index_time);

                NCdumpW.printArray(data.reduce(), "prate", System.out, null);
                NCdumpW.printArray(data_reftime.reduce(), "reftime", System.out, null);

                Integer val_reftime = data_reftime.getInt(data_reftime.getIndex().set(0));
                System.out.println(basetime.plusHours(val_reftime).toString());
                System.out.println(basetime.plusHours(val_reftime+index_time).toString());


                System.out.println(data_timeAll.getDouble(data_timeAll.getIndex().set(index_reftime,index_time)));
                System.out.println(basetime.plusHours(data_timeAll.getInt(data_timeAll.getIndex().set(index_reftime,index_time))).toString());

                System.out.println("=>");
                System.out.println(data_timeboundsAll.shapeToString());
                System.out.println(data_timeboundsAll.getDouble(data_timeAll.getIndex().set(index_reftime,index_time)));
                System.out.println(basetime.plusHours(data_timeboundsAll.getInt(data_timeboundsAll.getIndex().set(index_reftime,index_time))).toString());
            }
        }

} finally {
    if (null != vars.ncfile) try {
        vars.ncfile.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}

    Variable lat = ncfile.findVariable(latName);
    Variable lon = ncfile.findVariable(lonName);
    Variable time = ncfile.findVariable(timeName);
    Variable reftime = ncfile.findVariable(reftimeName);
    Variable time_bounds = ncfile.findVariable(time_boundsName);
```

Comment: Which version of netcdfAll.jar are you using?

Comment: @SeanA. I'm using 4.6.13